# How to bind itemsource in combobox based on another combox items in wpf?

Tags: wpf

If i have items in one combobox are CFG_REG,INT_REG,ST_REG,CMD_REG(which are defined in enum), if i select item CFG_REG then i should display GCR,PCR,LCR,CR,GSR,PSR in another combobox similarly,if i select INT_REG i should display IE,IS like that,.. How do i do that?

```
     <ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding CMDIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      x:Name="Combobox1"
                      Margin="0,0,1,0"  
                      VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    </ComboBox>   

     <ComboBox Grid.Column="3"  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      x:Name="combobox2" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding RegisterIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      Margin="0,0,1,0">

                    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind a collection of items (i.e. ICollection or Observable collection) in your view model/Code to the first Combo box's itemsSource. You can bind the 'SelectedItem' of the first combo box to a property in the code behind/view model and then in the setter of this property, you should filter out another Collection which will be bound to other Combo box. I hope you get the idea.

For example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource ={Binding Collection1} SelectedItem ={Binding SelectedItem} .../>
```

In the Code:

```
public ICollection Collection1 {get;set;}
public ICollection Collection2 {get;set;}

public string SelectedItem
{
get {..}
set{
SelectedItem = value;
ChangeSecondCollection(value);
}

public void ChangeSecondCollection(string value)
{
Collection2 = //Filter your second collection here.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting, can you elabarate with example i mentioned above @rohit-garg